# Users who have created most number of content (node) drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I am trying to create a block which displays the users who have created most number of content(nodes) in the site... how can I do this? for example "List of users who have written most number of articles"

Answer (score 0):

Check [User Activity Module](http://drupal.org/project/user_activity).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data with a simple SQL query on the node table. My SQL is a little rusty but it would be something like this:

```
SELECT uid, count(nid) FROM node WHERE type = 'whatever' GROUP BY uid ORDER BY count(nid) DESC
```

First result will be the user will the most nodes of type whatever, second result user with the second most nodes, etc. etc. Then just parse the results and shove it into a block. I'm not going to write how to do all that though :)